# Vim formula to leave only two first words in each line

Tags: regex, vim, replace

How to leave only two first words (remove all the rest) in each line in Vim?

E.g.

```
AA  AA  subst:pl:acc:m3+subst:pl:acc:n2
aa  ad acta brev:npun
```

into

```
AA  AA
aa  ad
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applied to all lines:

```
:%s/\v^(\s*\S+\s+\S+).+/\1/
```

Comment: Thank you for such a fast answer! This does the thick :)

Comment: What does the  `\v` at the start means?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: `:help \v`

Answer (score 5):

You can use my beloved `:normal` command:

```
:%norm EElD
```

or AWK:

```
:%!awk '{print $1, $2}'
```

or a substitution, if the real file doesn't look like the sample provided:

```
:%s/\S\+\s\+\S\+\zs.*
```

Comment: :D I almost fell in love with it, too, but please note your first line leaves the first line in the file UNCHANGED!

Comment: No it doesn't do that.

Comment: EElD doesn't work if some lines contain fewer than two words, was just working on adding this to my answer, but I couldn't fix that.

Comment: `EElD` works for the problem as described by the OP and the given sample.

Comment: How would you solve it with a sample line of "oneword"?

Comment: I would do it differently (with a substitution, as in your answer) because it would be a different problem.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot provide 'reproducible example'.

Comment: Then you must provide a realistic sample or explain how you simplified your sample.

Comment: :( Was hoping for something with :norm in that case. I've just recently discovered it's usefulness and realize why you say beloved.

Comment: @FredNurk, `:normal` is an amazing tool but it doesn't work for everything. Vim is all about context. Some methods will work better than others for the task at hand. It is perfect for the problem *as described by the OP* but not for the *real* problem. Finding the right tool for the job is a skill that comes over time but it depends heavily on one's ability to describe the problem to others and to himself.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a macro:

```
<ESC>gg
qa2wDj0
q
```

and repeating this using

```
@a
```

You can specify count by saying

```
n@a
```